# scoring run of 3 being under 31 by one player

Tags: cribbage

If player 2 lays down 3 consective cards with a total of 30, (king, queen, jack) with player 1 having to go, how do you count that?
Do you score 3 for the run and 1 for last card?

Comment: 1) you use 'player 1', 'player 2' and 'you' in the question, it's not clear who is who, could you please reword? 2) the answer depends on what the next action of the player in question would be (e.g. play a card or just peg for the last card), which also is not specified in the question. A minor nit-pick, in cribbage players alternate, so a single player could not possible lay down 3 consecutive cards, they would be alternating with opponents. I'm assuming that by 3 consecutive cards you just mean a run consisting of cards from both players.

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh: If, for example, Dealer kept TQQQ while Non-Dealer kept J234, then the play could go J-T-2(go)-3-4-point Q(go)-Q-Q-point-point, with both payers in turn playing three consecutive cards. There are many other variations on this.